# HTML 5 offline storage cache manifest not working for mobile

Tags: html, manifest, offlineapps, offline-browsing

I created a web app for mobile i want that i can use it offline too.
i use a manifest file its working fine with desktop browser but not working with mobile browser.
What is the problem?
thanks in advance...

Comment: What is the mobile browser?  Do you have a URL for the app?

Answer (score 0):

For the iPad, the cache manifest file MUST BE named as "cache.manifest".

if you want to dedub the code then

[Blog Post](http://jonathanstark.com/blog/2009/09/27/debugging-html-5-offline-application-cache/)

Comment: I named the cache manifest as "cache.manifest" but still its not working on my mobile. I save the app on my home screen also.

Comment: try this if it help you 
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1945-Using-The-Cache-Manifest-With-iPhone-s-App-Mode-For-Native-Web-Applications.htm